# How do I select all text in vistual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code (1.29.1) ctrl+a doesn't do anything for me. I checked keyboard shortcuts and it's mapped to a few select all actions (editor.action.selectAll, etc.) but when I'm in a file and press it nothing happens. How do I select all text in the current file in visual studio code?

Comment: Are you sure? I've the same version on Mac osx and command+a (that's the same of ctrl+a on Windows) select all text as usual

Comment: What OS? I am running VS Code on Win 10 and Mac OS X, `ctrl+a` (and `command+a`) works for me on both, respectively. Try reinstalling VS Code maybe?

Comment: Hm, ok. I'm on windows 10. It's weird it doesn't work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, it make me realize it must be an environmental issue. Turns out if you have any mapping starting with a key combination that will lock that mapping to the key combo and you can't use it for anything else.
To make save all ctrl+shift+s I had to re-map save as and I mapped it to ctrl+a+s, so everytime I hit ctrl+a it just waiting for second key. In the status bar at the bottom of my editor it said something like "Ctrl+a detected, waiting for second keystroke", which means Ctrl+a won't work on its own. I re-mapped Save As to some unused key combo and it fixed select all.

Answer (score 1):

This question was luckily answered on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302917/ctrl-a-to-select-all-not-working-in-visual-code)

I'll post the [OG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67051887/16052696) here, nonetheless.

Most new comers to VS-Code could resolve this issue with the 2nd method provided by the OG answer:

- Goto `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`
- in the search bar type this `Select All`
- There's should a couple of results, you'll obviously want the "Select All" result
- right click on his line and click on `Change When Expression`
- a textbox would be highlight for you to fill in text. type `editorFocus`
- press enter and done!

The OG answer provides image if you need to confirm that you're doing it right.

---

side-note: This issue bugged for more than 3 years and is the main reason my I used VS-Community over VS-Code.

So it's nice to finally be able to work normally in this very robust customizable IDE text-editor.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I agree, have enjoyed this over VS Community or Jetbrains Rider but the lack of select all working has been bugging me for months.