# Ctrl + A and similar selection manipulation shortcuts not working in visual code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Select all, copy, cut, and paste are not working by using the usual keyboard shortcuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + a, c, x, or v.

Comment: Isn't there another program opened, that catches the hotkey? I have similar problems generally when a remote desktop is open on another monitor for example.

Comment: No only edge browser  is open

Comment: Open "Preferences/ Keyboard shortcuts" and check two things: What's the binding for "Select All" and whether Ctrl+A is assigned for something else.

Comment: its Ctrl + A and for rest shortcuts for copy cut and paste as well as are correct but still not working

Comment: I have the same problem. From my side only the "select all" is not working

Answer (score 10):

for VS Code 1.55.1 I resolved this problem by 2 ways :

1. simply by uploading the keymaps of my long favorite editor as proposed by the manual https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings:

[image]

so follow the menu :

> File > Preferences > Keymaps

2. correcting manually the keyboard shortcuts which was in my case curiously corrupted, lacking of the necessary "when clause context" which was set with "-"
   However just open the keyboard shortcuts :

> File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Search the command "Select All" then right click on "When" (clause context) and select the "Change When Expression"
[image: visual illustration]

and tape :

```
editorFocus
```

which command to the editor "Select All" when editor is set as Focus on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

More about the **when clause context** : [visual studio code api reference on "when clause context"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts)

Comment: I installed VS Code not long ago and the issue still occurs until I found your answer.
Big thanks, and I'll be sure to share this answer on another Q that asked the same question

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same issue like you in VS code.
It is probably because you installed the extension like Vim which changed the key binding like crtl + a and others.
To fix it simply, you just uninstall that extension and reload the VS Code and it should be working fine after that.
[image]

Comment: In this instance, rather than uninstalling the vim instance, set `vim.useCtrlKeys` to `false` on "settings.json". 
Doc: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#windows

Comment: @Reincoder yup, that's a proper way to do it. But in my case, I'm not using that Vim extension and I just simply uninstall it to solve that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Search **select all** in *keyboard shortcuts* and then change then **when** to *editorTextFocus*